# If converting a Facebook profile to a Facebook page then is the username retained?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, url, username, user-accounts

Facebook provides a facility to convert a profile to a page. But is the username also transferred to the page? (that is what I want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the username becomes your new page username. Additionally your current profile photo will become the page's profile photo.

[Converting your personal profile to a page profile](http://www.facebook.com/help?page=213602951994043)

Comment: +1 and accepted - thanks for the link supporting your answer - here is the section on that page that confirms the answer: `http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=158425527557312#Will-all-the-content-on-my-timeline-be-transferred-when-I-convert-my-personal-account-to-a-Page?` "Your username will become your Page's username"